# Replace nth regex issue

Tags: sed

If I want to remove the first period and everything behind it from a string, in `sed` I can e.g. do:

```
echo 2.6.0.3-8 | sed 's/\..*//'
```

Output:

```
2
```

But if I want to remove the second period and everything behind it, I think I should be able to do it like this (GNU sed):

```
echo 2.6.0.3-8 | sed 's/\..*//2g'
```

However the output is:

```
2.6.0.3-8
```

From the manual:

> 'NUMBER'
>        Only replace the NUMBERth match of the REGEXP.

What have I missed here?

Comment: You're missing that it's greedy.  `.*` is gobbling everything up and there is no second match.  You can use `[^.]*` to better effect than `.*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're there but for getting burned by `.*` and greediness.  All you have to do for your specific case is replace `.*` with `[^.]*`:

```
$ echo 2.6.0.3-8 | sed 's/\.[^.]*//2g'
2.6
$ echo 2.6.0.3-8 | sed 's/\.[^.]*//3g'
2.6.0
$ echo 2.6.0.3-8 | sed 's/\.[^.]*//1g'
2
```

`[^.]` means all characters that aren't a dot.

Comment: +1, I see and with `g` it replaces the rest of the line as well. Note that this makes it a GNU specific sed. Do you know of a portable solution with sed?

Comment: I believe Glenn's is portable.  `-E` is more POSIX then the `-r` suggested by GNU sed's man page, but `-E` will work with GNU sed.

Comment: Yes you are right. However he does not use the `s///n` form I wanted to have working. I found a slightly hackish way around that, see my answer

Comment: Based on the discussion I added to your answer, these aren't portable to busybox sed.  You *cannot* fix wth `2\g`... I can't find a way to convince it to work with a numeral and the g option.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the expression is greedy. The first match consumes `.6.0.3-8`, and there is no text left for a second match.

You'll have to be more precise with your regex

```
$ sed -E 's/([^.]+(\.[^.]+){3}).*/\1/' <<<"2.6.0.3-8"
2.6.0.3-8
$ sed -E 's/([^.]+(\.[^.]+){2}).*/\1/' <<<"2.6.0.3-8"
2.6.0
$ sed -E 's/([^.]+(\.[^.]+){1}).*/\1/' <<<"2.6.0.3-8"
2.6
$ sed -E 's/([^.]+(\.[^.]+){0}).*/\1/' <<<"2.6.0.3-8"
2
```

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, this works fine, good answer. However it does not use the `s///n` form as I was trying to do in the question.

Comment: See @steve's answer on how to do it with GNU sed and mine for a slightly hackish but portable way

Answer (score 1):

As noted by both @stevesliva and @glennjackman, the issue here is that the regular expression matches the whole line, so there *is* no second match.

There does not seem to be a generic way to achieve the substitution with regex-only. So a generic alternative that removes the second period and everything behind it is to use `P` and `d`, e.g.:

```
echo 2.6.0.3-8 | sed 's/\./\n/2; P; d'
```

Or portably:

```
echo 2.6.0.3-8 | sed -e $'s/\\./\\\n/2' -e P -e d
```

Output in both cases:

```
2.6
```

Comment: Ahh, now I see. I did not catch your focus on a numeral combined with `g` being undefined behavior.  That said, the semicolons should be portable?  The usual portability issue I see with BSD sed users on OSX is that there must be a final semicolon within curly braces.

Comment: @stevesliva: Indeed I would also think so, but the above fails with Debian's busybox sed when using semi-colon separation

Comment: I'd guess that's more an issue of busybox unwrapping the single quoted string before passing it to busybox sed.  ie:  `$ echo 's/\./\n/2' | sed -f-` causes `sed: file - line 1: unterminated s' command` while `$ echo 's/\\./\\\n/2' | sed -f-` has no syntax error.  It's basically a shell expansion issue.  Sed's not seeing the right command string unless you allow for two passes of string expansion.

Comment: @stevesliva: But then it doesn't work, see e.g.: `echo 's/\\./\\\n/2' | sed -f /dev/stdin infile`, where infile contains the version string

Comment: I realized that I duplicate your issue and test this. `echo 2.6.0.3-8 | busybox sed 's/\./\n/2\;P;d'` seems to work just fine.  I thought the extra backslashes suggested expansion but it doesn't appear that you need them.   Busybox sed just can't tolerate the semicolon after the 2.  Which seems to be a bug, but that's a portability issue for you.